# JAVA @Query trying to look for non-existing table, corresponsing to Entity class-name

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've got a dependant service, who's sole purpose is to query every once in a while few tables of several kinds of customers we have (rejected, pending, etc) and create leads from them to send to our leads system. 
Since I do not need the exact customer entities, only a few details which are found in all tables (they are inherently different with only few common entries to identify customer), I have created an entity which is not supposed to be bound to a single table- but hold the results for all my queries:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Entity
public class LeadEntity {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String mobile;
    private String email;
    private String notes;
}
```

Also, I have created a repository with 4 queries to the 4 tables, lookin somewhat like this:

```
@Repository
public interface LeadsRepository extends JpaRepository<LeadEntity, Long> {
@Query(value =
        "select " +
                "    rc.id, " +
                "    rc.firstName as first_name, " +
                "    rc.lastName as last_name, " +
                "    rc.phoneNumber as mobile, " +
                "    rc.email as email, " +
                "    null as notes, " +
                "    null as age_of_youngest_driver, " +
                "    null as insurance_type, " +
                "    null as manufacturer, " +
                "    null as model, " +
                "    null as year, " +
                "    null as claims, " +
                "    null as experience, " +
                "    null as license_revocations, " +
                "    null as insurance_start_date, " +
                "    null as vehicle_type, " +
                "    null as policy_number " +
                "from " +
                "    rejected_customers rc " +
                "where " +
                "    rc.creationDate > ?1 and rc.creationDate < ?2 " +
                "    and rc.phoneNumber is not null", nativeQuery = true)
List<LeadEntity> findRejectedCustomers(Date begin, Date end);

}
```

Few things to note about that repository declaration:

1. you see only one query method here, I have 4 which all look the same style but from different tables and different columns.
2. the "null as X" syntax is here for historical reasons (means the programmer before me wrote that and I dont wanna ruin anything cuz i'm new at this job so im following the same pattern XD).
3. ALL queries has "nativeQuery = true" so they should be executed exactly as written to my understanding. Also each query refers to a different table (some got "join" inside as well).

The piece of code executing them is inside a schedualer and is as simple as that:

```
        leadsRepository.findRejectedCustomers(beginOfTimePeriod, endOfTimePeriod)
                .forEach(this::createLead);

        leadsRepository.findPendingPackages(beginOfTimePeriod, endOfTimePeriod)
                .forEach(this::createLead);

        leadsRepository.findIncompleteOffers(beginOfTimePeriod, endOfTimePeriod)
                .forEach(this::createLead);

        leadsRepository.findNoClaimsPackages(beginOfTimePeriod, endOfTimePeriod)
                .forEach(this::createLead);
```

**And here is the problem:**
The first query after a successful query throws me an error: 
SQLGrammerException: table "lead_entry" does not exist.

note the weird situation its happening in:
ONLY after a query succeeds and return results, the next one after it will fail with this exception.
No matter what order I execute them in.
No matter which query works and which one comes after it.
EVERY combination I tried yielded the same results- this error (except for the case when no-query returned error- pointed it at an empty DB, so all queries passed cleanly).

I'M CLUELESS!!
Will give any information you guys want.... but I have no idea where to start with this.

HELP!

EDIT: here is the stack trace for the error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:279)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:253)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:138)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy74.findPendingPackages(Unknown Source)
    at com.bambidynamic.leadwize.main.scheduler.Scheduler.periodic(Scheduler.java:88)
    at com.bambidynamic.leadwize.main.scheduler.Scheduler$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b155d9d1.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at com.bambidynamic.leadwize.main.scheduler.Scheduler$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7cb743e5.periodic(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3358)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3231)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3632)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:356)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1453)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1439)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.beforeQuery(NativeQueryImpl.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1503)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:132)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:129)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:91)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:125)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'newBambi.lead_entity' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:955)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1094)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1042)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1345)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1027)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175)
    ... 61 more
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post and include the stack trace.

Comment: What is in createLead?

Comment: Annotating with Entity a class that is clearly not an entity, but just the result of some query, is a bad idea to begin with. Don't do that.

Comment: @Turing85 Done!
@aksappy nothing really, just putting the gathered data into different object and sending it to leads system via WSDL-configured api... want me to paste the content of `createLead` as well?
@JBNizet If I take down the `@Entity`, the process just exists (`Process finished with exit code 1`) when I start it- not even going into my `init()` function which is decorated with `@PostConstruct`... Any ideas what else could I put there to make it work? and why annotating with @Entity for a non-entity class is such a bad idea? I realize its not the intended use, but can it really harm?

Comment: Maybe you can enable sql log?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri how do I do that?

Comment: @Gibor add this `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` and 
`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true` to your application.properties

Comment: hmm those are already in our applicaion.yml file... should it effect the log? @GiorgiTsiklauri

Comment: You should see the generated SQL queries in your console log..

Comment: `could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]` - seems like it is trying its best to show me the sql, but to no avail...